# Wagtail: How to setup up unittest for simple page edit?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am trying to setup a simple test in Wagtail with *django-pytest* and *wagtail_factories* to test the ability of users to edit `Pages` they own. But I keep beeing redirect when I try to get the edit url. (For my example here I use a superuser fixture to not have to deal with permissions.)

```
# test_views.py

def test_user_can_edit_owned_pages(client, superuser):
    parent_page = MyPageIndexPageFactory()
    my_page = MyPageFactory(owner=superuser, parent=parent_page)

    edit_url = reverse("register_mypage_modeladmin_edit", args=[my_page.pk])

    client.force_login(superuser)
    response = client.get(edit_url)
    
    # to capture in pytests output  
    print(
        superuser.is_superuser, 
        my_page.id, 
        response
    )    

    assert response.status_code == 200
```

The `assert` fails although the captured output shows that the `Page` get’s created with the correct ID in the url – but I am beeing redirect nevertheless.

```
True 4778 <HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/admin/pages/4778/edit/?next=/admin/my_app/mypage/">
```

When I get the index url for the list view of my model all is good.

```
    [...]
    index_url = reverse("register_mypage_modeladmin_index")
    response = client.get(index_url)
    qs = response.context[0]["object_list"]
    print(qs)
```

Captured output: `<PageQuerySet [<MyPage: Test Page>]>`

I'd suspect that this is (still) an permissions problem even though I am using a `superuser`.  How would one setup a simple test like this in Wagtail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL route you're accessing (`register_mypage_modeladmin_edit`) is part of the modeladmin module, which does indeed [redirect to the standard page edit view when you use it on a page model](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html#summary-of-features):

> For Page models, the system directs to Wagtail’s existing add and edit views, and returns you back to the correct list page, for a seamless experience.

So, what you're seeing is Modeladmin working as designed. Perhaps you intended to run this test against the standard page edit view instead? If so, the URL route you want is `wagtailadmin_pages:edit`.

Comment: [facepalm] You are absolutely right, that was my intention. It works now, of course.